# How to add ended slash in link appearing below browser while hovering

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I want to add slash at the end of this link when hovering on logo (WordPress)

[image]

I expect to find link like `https://lacosta-realestate.com/` when hovering on logo

Comment: Why do you need the slash at the end? The link still works doesn't it?

Comment: @FewtureWebdesign I want it for SEO

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permalink structure under settings > permalinks.
Here you can define a custom permalink structure and add a trailing slash explicitly.

You can find a more detailed tutorial [here](https://permalinkmanager.pro/docs/plugin-settings/how-to-add-remove-trailing-slashes/#:%7E:text=Even%20users%20who%20are%20unfamiliar,will%20have%20the%20trailing%20slash.).

Comment: I changed the permalink structure as you said but still does not work